# For loop only executes once when calling function in flutter

Tags: firebase, flutter, dart, firebase-storage

This is my first experience with Flutter, just trying to create a super simple app that uploads a bunch of photos to firebase-storage to assist our media & marketing teams internally.

I have successfully implemented multi_image_picker, I can select images and build out the grid view, the images are stored in a list.

I have an upload button, when pressed it calls a uploadImages Function which should loop over the list of images created by multi_image_picker and call the saveImage function to save the images to Firebase.

While it triggers, it only ever uploads a single image and never the entire list as such, the for looop never seems to keep running.

Button to Call uploadImages function:

```
RaisedButton(
              child: Text("Upload Images"),
              onPressed: () {
                uploadImages(images);
              },),
```

uploadImages function with for loop:

```
void uploadImages(List<Asset> images) async {
    for (var i = 0; i < images.length; i++) {
      await saveImage(images[i]);
    }
  }
```

Finally the saveImage function that works, but only ever uploads a single image:

```
Future saveImage(Asset i) async {
    ByteData byteData = await i.getByteData();
    List<int> imageData = byteData.buffer.asUint8List();
    StorageReference ref =
        FirebaseStorage.instance.ref().child("$now " + "$displayName.jpg");
    StorageUploadTask uploadTask = ref.putData(imageData);
    StorageTaskSnapshot storageSnapshot = await uploadTask.onComplete;
    var downloadURL = await storageSnapshot.ref.getDownloadURL();
    if (uploadTask.isComplete) {
      final String url = downloadURL.toString();
      return url;
    } else {
      print('Error from image repo ${storageSnapshot.error.toString()}');
    }}
```

I've tried to many different things, found a few errors with debugger and resolved, but after days of trying I am just unable to get it to keep uploading the images per the for loop. Can someone see what I have done wrong here?

Comment: Have you verified that `uploadImages` is given a `List` with more than one element and that the `List` can't be mutated while `uploadImages` is in-flight?

Comment: Yes, in debug I inspected and could see that the uploadImages List had 2 objects which aligned with the 2 images I had selected in the image picker. The loop, to my understanding should then pass off the first image of the array to the saveImage function which when returned should be passed the second image asset. In debug, the whole thing terminates after the saveImage function returns the URL i.e. it never goes back to the for loop.

Comment: You didn't answer my second question: is it possible that `List` is mutated between iterations? (A simple way to verify would be to pass `uploadImages` a *copy* of `images`: `uploadImages([...images])`.)

Comment: Im going to say no.. I updated the onPressed to : `uploadImages([...images]);` 

Then inspected the images list in the uploadImages function and it still had two assets as was originally passed. 

It still only uploaded a single image.

Comment: Does it behave any differently if you temporarily unroll the loop (i.e., temporarily hard-code `uploadImages` to call `await saveImage(images[0]); await saveImage(images[1]);`?

Comment: It still only uploaded 1 image, but was the second image in the array not the first, so it failed to upload `saveImage(images[0]);` but did upload `saveImage(images[1]);`

Comment: How do you know that only one image was uploaded?  Are you expecting that `"$now " + "$displayName.jpg` generates a unique filename for each image?  Nothing in the code you've shown would make it unique.

Comment: Yes, thats correct, I had assumed $now is `var now = DateTime.now();` which provides time down to sss that the filename would be unique as the function is getting executed at a different point in time. It had crossed my mind that I may be getting a conflicting file name causing only a single image to show.

What can you add to make the filename more unique?

Comment: `saveImage` doesn't call `DateTime.now()`, so if `now` is set somewhere else, it's going to be the same for all calls to `saveImage`.  Even if `saveImage` did call `DateTime.now()`, you wouldn't be *guaranteed* to get a unique name.  You could just have a simple counter, or have `uploadImages` pass an index or filename to `uploadImage`.

Comment: @jamesdlin yep, it was clashing file names. Fantastic work leading to a solution. Can you post this as a response and I will happily mark it as the correct solution. NB: I have replaced with my original for loop and its now working as expected there too.